# Rscript does not have "is" function

Tags: r, rscript

I am trying to run some R scripts from the command line using Rscript.  I have tried on both mac and linux and run into the following problem on both.  The test script below works perfectly fine if I just type it into R:

```
is
```

The script just prints out the function "is".  However, if I put it in a file like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
is
```

and then run it using either "./test.R" or "Rscript test.R", I get the following error:

```
Error: object 'is' not found
Execution halted
```

It seems that the "is" function is not defined in Rscript as it is in R.  How can I make my script work?

**Note**: Obviously my goal is not just to print out the "is" function.  I'm trying to use gamlss, and the "is" function is called by gamlss, resulting in this error.

**Edit**:  In R, the sessionInfo() gives:

```
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.0.2
```

From Rscript, it gives:

```
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  base
```

Comment: What do you get from the output of `sessionInfo()` both in an interactive session and called from Rscript.

Comment: I'll add the sessionInfo output to my question.  Basically, you were right.  The sessionInfo() shows that the "methods" package is attached in R but not in Rscript.

Comment: In `?Rscript` they say this: "The default for ‘Rscript’ omits ‘methods’ as it takes about 60% of the startup time."

Comment: Ah, I missed that somehow.  It took me a while to realize that "is" is part of "methods" instead of "base", I guess.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the solution is to load the "methods" package (which contains the "is" function).  I guess it is loaded by default in R, but not in Rscript for some reason.  If I change my script to:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
library(methods)
is
```

then it works fine from the command line.